# No connector for []

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, queue

I am using redis as my Queue_driver but when I try to run

```
php artisan queue:listen vvv
```

it says

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
 No connector for []
```

I have redis set up in my queue.php

```
    'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),
    'connections' => [
        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
],
```

and set the queuedriver in my .env file

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

composer.json

```
  "require":{
       "predis/predis":"~1.0",
```

Maybe worth to mention that I'm using docker to run my project and redis is working, I use it for caching and it works as expected.
Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you get when you try `CACHE_DRIVER=array`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the connection details in `config/database.php` (or specify the ENV vars):

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/
'redis' => [
    'client' => 'predis',
    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
],
```

This can be found right at the end of the file. (This one is taken from Laravel 5.4 and might be different depending on your version of Laravel).